# Drawing a waveform from a short AAC file on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, aac, waveform

I'm trying to draw a waveform for a short AAC audio file (can't convert to WAV as they come from a web service) on Android, and it's proving surprisingly tricky.

Here is an image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Note that the frame of the view will be fixed proportionally to the device's screen resolution, and will not need to stretch, or be zoomed at all. This means I can just set up an array of height values with length equal to the pixel width of the view at runtime. Also these audio files are short, so I'm not really worried about memory right now.

Now, if I understand corrently, the necessary steps are basically:

1. Decode the AAC audio into an array of bytes representing the amplitude of the wave.
2. Pull out a byte for each pixel on the x-axis to be displayed.
3. Override onDraw in my view and draw a line for each pixel on the x-axis.

However, I'm having trouble with step 1. I've tried:

1. JAAD (http://jaadec.sourceforge.net/usage.php), which looked promising, only to discover that it won't run on Android due to the absence of javax.sound.sampled.
2. The code provided in the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/11858709/269152 which actually works rather nicely to handle all steps (with a little editing of the code to remove all the zooming etc), except the waveform is really blocky, I think due to the way the audio is cut up into a small number of "frames", perhaps due to this being intended for longer files and zoomed by the user. I've been able to get more detail in the WAV handling by editing the CheapWAV class, but am not sure how to do it with the CheapAAC class.
3. Android's MediaCodec is not an option due to needing Android 4.1+. I need to support 2.3.
4. I've tried Android's Visualizer class in conjunction with a MediaPlayer, but all I was getting out of it was a 1024 length array of -128 values. It looks like the visualizer isn't designed to be used to scan files, but just to visualize playback as it happens? I can post the code if it's of any use. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html)

This was really easy on iOS using AVAssetReader to decode the audio for me. Am I missing something obvious? Is there an easy way for me to get the PCM values for an AAC file so I can plot them in my view? Or does someone know of an awesome view that handles all of this?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hmm, perhaps using ffmpeg could be an option? https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android

Comment: Update, I'm currently trying out a nice little ffmpeg wrapper at https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java. So far it seems to be converting an AAC to WAV for me using it's convertToWaveAudio method. Assuming things go well I'll post an answer with more details soon.

Comment: Your point number 1 is not valid. While you not using any class referencing javax.sound.* api you can use this library on Android. For example I was able to use it without any problems.

Comment: Hey Marky. I'm currently also working on drawing a waveform from AAC files. How did you finally got the necessary data, can you read it from AAC or does it have to be converted to PCM first?

Comment: Hi Milter, yes I ended up converting the AAC file to WAV, then drawing a waveform from that data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Marky. Did you use any library converting to WAV? I was playing around with Java Advanced Audio Decoder (jaadec.sourceforge.net), but for some reason i'm not getting any meaningful pcm data